# Как добавить разные стили в разные дивы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имею конструкцию https://jsfiddle.net/profy/nh6omc4k/40/

```
<div class="woosb_r">
<div>
<div>
<div class="woosb-qty woosb-qty-plus-minus">
  <div class="woosb-qty-input">
   <div class="woosb-qty-input-minus">эл.2 - клик сюда  удалить добавленные классы </div>   
   <div class="quantity">
                <label class="text">Количество</label>
            <input class="input-text qty text">
                  <span class="product-qty-arrows">
                  <span class="lnr lnr-chevron-up"></span>
                  <span class="chevron-down"></span>
              </span>
        </div>
   <div class="woosb-qty-input-plus">эл.1 - изменить фон - клик сюда  добавить класс к родителю "woosb_r", и в глубину соседнего дива ".woosb-price .woosb-price-ori +новый класс "
 </div>
</div>

<div class="woosb-price">
   <div class="woosb-price-ori">
                <del>vbv</del> 
        <ins>Это соседний DIV <br>И ЗДЕСЬ поменять ЦВЕТ ТЕКСТА при клике на эл.1</ins>                           </div>
 <div class="woosb-price-new"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Нужно при клике на один элемент добавить/изменить класс всего родителя и в глубине класс соседа, а при клике на другой элемент все вернуть как было (убрать/изменить класс)

вот здесь наверно  понятней получилось https://jsfiddle.net/profy/nh6omc4k/40/

Answer (score 2):

На JQuery:

```
$(".woosb_r").on('click', '.woosb-qty-input-plus', function () {
    $('.woosb_r, .woosb-price-ori').addClass('edited');
});

$(".woosb_r").on('click', '.woosb-qty-input-minus', function () {
    $('.woosb_r, .woosb-price-ori').removeClass('edited');
});
```

Comment: вечная проблема, код работает...нооо. добавляется стиль во всех блоках *woosb_r* а мне надо чтобы добалялся стиль только в том блоке в котором присходит клик....https://jsfiddle.net/profy/nh6omc4k/62/